# Process for Flaging a Moderator comment

Tags: discussion, flagging, moderators, moderation

If I flag a Moderator comment (as not constructive), does it get reviewed by another (independent) moderator or can the flagged moderator just delete/ignore it.

Just interested in the process here, since none of us is perfect and can make mistakes.

Here is a example (removed moderator name for privacy).

[image: flag moderator]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They'll show up in the comment queue and all moderators will see the flag. The system doesn't hide the flag from the moderator who's comment was flagged. We discuss flags on our own comments and avoid moderating ourselves.

Comment: I like the "avoid moderating ourselves", glad to hear there is more then the "accused" seen the Flag. Avoiding the embarrassing Et tu, Brute!-- "Truth will ultimately prevail where there is pains to bring it to light."

Comment: To say occurrences of moderators having comments flagged is rare is an understatement.

Comment: Nobody is perfect ! but also shall not have the ultimate power of deciding his/her faith.

Comment: @IanC. I just had to do this because a moderator [deleted an answer that says something exists as a duplicate of something that says it doesn't](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423605/command-control-shift-4-doesnt-work-how-to-capture-portion-of-screen-to-clipbo/4236130). I'm a moderator of a large dev forum (9K members) and only deleted an answer *once* in 16 years, when someone posted a copyrighted executable.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos moderators don't act unilaterally. Your answer was flagged _by the community_ as not unique. Stack Exchange isn't a forum. It's a Q&A site. I suggest taking a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour to familiarize yourself with how it works. You could have put your screenshot on the existing answer as an edit to improve it, for example, and helped make it more cogent. You can start a new meta question about what happened on your answer if you'd like to have it discussed in detail with the rest of the community.

Comment: @IanC. I already have 90K rep at SO. I know how these sites work, and I know that *deleting* someone's answer is one of the most extreme measures, taken only when an answer is very bad and gets multiple downvotes, not **up**votes. I've also spotted the patterns of negative communities quite a few times. And I don't like the pattern of behavior I've seen in just two days here. Not to me, but to people asking legitimate questions.